Tensorflow 2.17.0 build failed with bazel linux
I download the source code of tensorflow-2.17.0 from github, then i run 'configure' and build with bazel-6.5.0 successfully,
> bazel build //tensorflow/core:tensorflow

then i create a folder 'test' and add a file named 'test.cc' with an empty main function
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    return 0
}

the BUILD file:
cc_binary(
  name="test",
  srcs=["test.cc"],
  linkopts = [
        "-lpthread",
        "-lrt",
        "-ldl",
        "-lnsl",
        "-latomic",
  ],
  linkstatic = 1,
  deps=[
    "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow"
  ],
)

but when i run 'bazel build //test:test', there are a lot of link errors:
external/com_google_absl/absl/base/casts.h:161:42: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
                             int>::type = 0>
                                          ^
In file included from external/local_xla/xla/shape.h:29,
                 from external/local_xla/xla/index_util.h:24,
                 from external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:45,
                 from external/local_xla/xla/literal.cc:16:
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h: In instantiation of 'bool xla::LiteralBase::DeserializeState<InputIterator>::ReadElements(absl::lts_20230802::Span<NativeT>) [with NativeT = ml_dtypes::float8_internal::float8_e4m3fn; InputIterator = const char*]':
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:1528:44:   required from 'bool xla::LiteralBase::Piece::DeserializeData(xla::LiteralBase::DeserializeState<InputIterator>&) [with NativeT = ml_dtypes::float8_internal::float8_e4m3fn; InputIterator = const char*]'
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:1587:3:   required from 'xla::Literal::Deserialize(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const char*]::<lambda(const xla::ShapeIndex&, xla::LiteralBase::Piece*)>::<lambda(auto:5)> [with auto:5 = std::integral_constant<xla::PrimitiveType, (xla::PrimitiveType)20>]'
external/local_xla/xla/primitive_util.h:432:34:   required from 'constexpr R xla::primitive_util::FloatingPointTypeSwitch(F&&, xla::PrimitiveType) [with R = bool; F = xla::Literal::Deserialize(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const char*]::<lambda(const xla::ShapeIndex&, xla::LiteralBase::Piece*)>::<lambda(auto:5)>]'
external/local_xla/xla/primitive_util.h:480:40:   required from 'constexpr R xla::primitive_util::ArrayTypeSwitch(F&&, xla::PrimitiveType) [with R = bool; F = xla::Literal::Deserialize(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const char*]::<lambda(const xla::ShapeIndex&, xla::LiteralBase::Piece*)>::<lambda(auto:5)>]'
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:1587:3:   required from 'static absl::lts_20230802::StatusOr<xla::Literal> xla::Literal::Deserialize(InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = const char*]'
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:1390:62:   required from here
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:684:64:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'xla::primitive_util::BitWidth(((xla::PrimitiveType)primitive_type))'
external/local_xla/xla/primitive_util.h:568:54: error: 'constexpr int xla::primitive_util::internal::WidthForType(xla::PrimitiveType) [with const std::array<int, 28>& kWidths = xla::primitive_util::internal::kBitWidths]' called in a constant expression
   return internal::WidthForType<internal::kBitWidths>(type);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from external/local_xla/xla/literal.cc:16:
external/local_xla/xla/literal.h:686:23: error: static assertion failed
         static_assert(!primitive_util::IsFloatingPointType(primitive_type));

i don't know why i build a library with '//tensorflow/core:tensorflow' successfully but the binary command executes failed, here's some params of my environment:
system: Ubuntu-20.04 x64
gcc: 8.4.0

.tf_configure.bazelrc :
build --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/usr/bin/python3"
build --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"
build --python_path="/usr/bin/python3"
build:opt --copt=-Wno-sign-compare
build:opt --host_copt=-Wno-sign-compare
test --test_size_filters=small,medium
test:v1 --test_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss,-oss_excluded,-gpu,-oss_serial
test:v1 --build_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss,-oss_excluded,-gpu
test:v2 --test_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss,-oss_excluded,-gpu,-oss_serial,-v1only
test:v2 --build_tag_filters=-benchmark-test,-no_oss,-oss_excluded,-gpu,-v1only

when i build xla directly, same error occured:
> bazel build //tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla:xla_compiler --verbose_failures


We can see that the //tensorflow/core:tensorflow target depends on a build_config target, which smells like it might provide some flags.
Looking at that target, we can see that it has copts = tf_copts(), loaded at the top of the BUILD file, as well as making your link static.
Let's look at that definition. It provides heaps of copts, which will certainly change your outputs.
I'd suggest depending on this platform build config target for your target. It seems like it's designed to do most things for you.

i tried to move file to /tensorflow/core, and add tf_copts(), but still not work

@WardenAllen Try depending on //tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config:tensorflow_platform_specific
